# assignment from incompatible type c

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation, argv

I do not use C nor C++ too often but I'm about
to finish compiling a file that detects faces with opencv which is a copy of a c++ file that already does it for windows, is for tagging in a social network, the error I get with the code when compiling is the next one

```
In function 'main':
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

---

```
int main( int argc, char** argv[])
{
    char* dea;

    int i=0;
    while(i<argc)
    {
        if(i==1){
            dea=argv[i];
        }
        i++;
    }

    char image[400],temp_image[400];


    IplImage  *img,*temp_img;
    int       key;


    storage = cvCreateMemStorage( 0 );
    cascade = ( CvHaarClassifierCascade* )cvLoad( face_cascade, 0, 0, 0 );

    if( !(cascade) )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: Could not load classifier cascade\n" );
        return -1;
    }



    sprintf(image,"dimage%d.jpg");

    img=cvLoadImage(dea,0);
    temp_img=cvLoadImage(dea,0);

    if(!img)
    {
        printf("Could not load image file and trying once again: %s\n",image);
    }
    printf("\n curr_image = %s",image);

    detectFacialFeatures(img,temp_img);


    cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade( &cascade );
    cvReleaseMemStorage( &storage );

    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvReleaseImage(&temp_img);


    return 0;
}
```

I want to be able to send to argv[] as the first argument after the executable the location of the photo to be parsed therefore I have tried with a loop to assign to char* dea; the value of argv[i] when i is 1.

I would do dea=argv[1]

but that throws a different kind of error so I took this approach.

Comment: Please post the full error message or a minimal, compilable testcase.

Comment: argv should be char** type and not char*** type

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Argv should be declared as `char **argv`, or `char *argv[]`, but you declared it as `char **argv[]` that is a *triple* pointer.

You're trying to assign a `char *` to a `char`.

Comment: yes, it was that, it now compiled perfectly will pick as answer when I can (missing minutes to be able to pick right answer). later

Answer (score 3):

I think you have your args declared  wrong
it should be

```
char** args
```

or

```
char* args[]
```

not

```
char** args[]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dea=argv[i];
```

You are assigning a double pointer `char** argv[]` to a single pointer `char* dea` . If you wanna assign the value of argv to dea then take dea as double pointer.

```
char** dea;
dea[i] = argv[i];
```